# how to sign ".apk" file on an Android Phone?

Tags: android, apk, jarsigner

I want to generate an new ".apk" file on the phone (a function in my app-market like app), and I have to sign it before install it. I think I have to run the JarSigner on the phone.

JarSigner is found in the following two project: OpenJDK and GCC-libjava.

I have tried to include OpenJDK.jar I downloaded from Internet but it doesn't have JarSigner class in it.

I also have tried to add JarSigner.java from OpenJDK source to my Android APP Project, but the dependencies are way too much. Same with JarSigner.java from GCC-LibJAVA.

it's too difficult to implement a new JarSigner for Android.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to create .apk using your phone , have a look at this :

**JavaIDEdroid** allows you to create native Android applications on Android devices.

http://code.google.com/p/java-ide-droid/

Comment: this should help. I'm looking into it

Comment: Signing of an application with your own keys works in paid version of the JavaIDEdroid only :-(

Answer (score 2):

I successfully signed my application on my Android device with my own key using the "ZipSigner" Android aplication, Licensed under Apache 2.0.
Application site: https://sites.google.com/site/zipsigner/
At Google play: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=kellinwood.zipsigner2

See the screenshot: [image: Signing Android application with ZipSigner on an Android device]

BTW, 
1. All previous steps of the application build may be done in the TerminalIde Android application ( http://www.spartacusrex.com/terminalide.htm ). Unfortunately, current version of the application doesn't support signing with custom keys.
2. The ZipSigner application is part of the "zip-signer" Open Source project: https://code.google.com/p/zip-signer/