# Re-signing apps (.apk, .air) on Android Devices. Commandline-like

Tags: android, air, apk, keytool, sign

On a not rooted android device there is a ssh server. Let's say on it i have a .apk-debug package with an app and want to change a file in it. I know i have to re-sign it or sign it again. Normally on a PC computer i have java jdk installed with keytool and jarsigner tools available from command line. I was not able to run jdk for arm processors commands like javac on my Android device because i had no permissions, my device is not rooted.

How can i re-sign an apk or air file from command line (ssh server) without root permissions.

It is needed form me because i am working on an automated system for creating multiplatform apps based mainly on PHP server Andro PHP installed on an Android device (or ssh-server manually). A PHP script would re-sign apk or air files launching re-signing commands. But it has to use keytool or jarsigner.

Nowadays i have to do all the stuff on the PC computer working as a server because of there is working JDK there but wanted to port it entirely into android devices also.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to sign ".apk" file on an Android Phone?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14018002/how-to-sign-apk-file-on-an-android-phone)

Comment: I cannot find there how can i use command-line tools to invoke some commands from commandline or from a php script or how could i get there using for example change dir command cd dirone/dirtwo/ and then signingcommand -option one

Comment: Than you for the information. You know it is a matter of automation, not having a rooted device too. I am not a Android proffesional so i need some explanation too. I don't see at the moment it duplicates the topic you mentioned though it has a lot in common. Command-line (via ssh terminal for example) is a keyword.

Comment: Signing an apk is not a built-in feature of the android OS so you need to install a third-party app to do it (or develop a jar-signer yourself). Once installed/done you can probably invoke it programmatically.

Comment: Right. Developping a jar-signer is beyond my available time and current capability. So maybe there will be anyone able to give me/us some piece of information about any such an app accessible from commandline (or php script). And if he gave some understandable tips what to write in the commandline too...

Comment: Some information. I stumbled on a website some time ago where there was some information on translating from jarsigner or keytool to Open SSL and vice versa. So, it is possible and PHP has some Open SSL tools built in as i know. But i can do nothing with this information. It is for visitors.

Comment: post the link to this website can be helpful

Comment: Found in my browser's history (There is a link there to the oposite direction, and actually there is even more such information there) http://conshell.net/wiki/index.php/Keytool_to_OpenSSL_Conversion_tips

Answer (score 1):

This can be done via the command line on a non-rooted device if you have the free ZipSigner app installed from Google Play.  You will have to setup the app to sign with your private key first, and then the app can be controlled via the command line to sign files with it.  The command line command is:

```
am start -a kellinwood.zipsigner.action.SIGN_FILE --es inputFile <inputFile> --es outputFile <outputFile> --es keyMode <keyName>
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you Ken for your precious time. It seems to be somewhat a breakthrough answer. Yet, being little experienced i need some time to analyse it and translate all this into my ignorant thoughts. I've just tested the am start command via windows putty ssh connection to my phone (i am not an Android developer) and it is one of few commands with no permission denied output. By the way. I've recently written to the author of the program :) .

Comment: At the moment i cannot check whether i can start any command (not only am start ....) from php script on my phone. Because my browser doesn't output when exec, system, passthru, popen functions are invoked. There is no error information. I know that on my old tablet i saw some outputs using those php commands. Maybe i'll later try with redirecting output to a file using unix like commands if i have permissions to do that. I'll write some time later.